# spaCy: `Can't find model 'en'` when deploying on GCloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud, spacy

I have trained some NLP models and also done up a Flask app to wrap the models into an API for front-end clients to call. All is well until I attempted to deploy the Flask app on Google Cloud's App Engine following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_zD8jfVQJ4).

On GCloud, I use the Cloud Shell to deploy the Flask app using `gcloud app deploy` and it keeps throwing the error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I have also attempted various solutions proposed in many other SO posts but all did not resolve the issue:

```
python3 -m spacy download en
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
sudo python3 -m spacy download en
sudo python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I also attempted to run a local python shell on the Cloud Shell with simple `hello world` but it somehow worked:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Nov 13 2019, 23:27:19)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> test = "hello world"
>>> nlp(test)
hello world
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things to get this working.

1. Instead of loading Spacy lang module using spacy command, use pip to install it. 
   Modify the `requirements.txt` to add the following line:

   `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz#en_core_web_sm`
2. Modify your code to load the lang model by the exact package name since the directory link is no more created for us

`spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

Thats all there is to it. Deploy your app again and it should work fine.